# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. How to resolve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 if w<h:
        normalized_char = np.ones((h, h), dtype='uint8')
        start = (h-w)/2
        normalized_char[:, start:start+w] = char
    else:
        normalized_char = np.ones((w, w), dtype='uint8')
        start = (w-h)/2
        normalized_char[start:start+h, :] = char
```

Running this on jupyter and getting this error

```
<ipython-input-8-15d17de04b9c> in extractCharactersNew(function)
     60             normalized_char = np.ones((h, h), dtype='uint8')
     61             start = (h-w)/2
---> 62             normalized_char[:, start:start+w] = char
     63         else:
     64             normalized_char = np.ones((w, w), dtype='uint8')

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

How Can I resolve this error?

Comment: `(h-w)/2` is floating-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is:-

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

`slice indices`, in your case refer to the variables that you are using to slice the list in

```
normalized_char[:, start:start+w] = char
```

That is - `start` and `start+w`. For list slicing, these must be integers or have an `__index__` method.  This `__index__` method is a special method that returns integer value for that object.
You should be able to solve your issue by ensuring that you provide correct `slice indices`. You can use `start = (h-w)//2`(integer division) to make sure that start is an integer.