# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to find the index of v but it always gives me:
`'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'`

I've tried:
[TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method. How to resolve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504523/typeerror-slice-indices-must-be-integers-or-none-or-have-an-index-method-h)
[How to find the index of an array within an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488005/how-to-find-the-index-of-an-array-within-an-array).
[Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top)

none of them have answered my question

```
v = np.random.randn(10)
print(v)
maximum = np.max(v)
minimum = np.min(v)
print(maximum, minimum)
v.index(maximum, minimum)
```

edit: Oh, crap i put ma instead of maximum my bad. I just started programing then.

Comment: what is `ma` and `mi` ?

Comment: what do you mean by saying `index `??

Comment: also it look like youre looking for `np.where()`

Comment: @Likedapro see my answer

Comment: `index` is a list method. `v` is a numpy array.  There's a difference.

Comment: lol I dont even know what im doing. this was like a long time ago rip.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### First of all, `index` is a list method. Here `v` is a numpy array and you need to do the following:

```
v = np.random.randn(10)
print(v)
maximum = np.max(v)
minimum = np.min(v)
print(maximum, minimum)

index_of_maximum = np.where(v == maximum)
index_of_minimum = np.where(v == minimum)
```

### Get the elements using these indices:

```
v[index_of_minimum]
v[index_of_maximum]
```

### Verify using assert:

```
assert(v[index_of_maximum] == v.max())
assert(v[index_of_minimum] == v.min())
```

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Numpy:

```
values = np.array([3,6,1,5])
index_min = np.argmin(values)
print(index_min)
```

returns the index of 2.